# How to remove the default cropping in WinRT after camera capture

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime

I am using the below given method for camera capturing in my WinRT application,

```
        var camera = new CameraCaptureUI();
        var aspectRatio = new Size(16, 9);
        camera.PhotoSettings.CroppedAspectRatio = aspectRatio;
        var file = await camera.CaptureFileAsync(CameraCaptureUIMode.Photo);
        if (file != null)
        {
            var fileStream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
            var bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
            bitmapImage.SetSource(fileStream);
            var imageDimension = Utilities.GetImageDimension(bitmapImage.PixelWidth, bitmapImage.PixelHeight);
            SourceImage = new WriteableBitmap((int)imageDimension.Item1, (int)imageDimension.Item2);
            var imageStream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
            SourceImage.SetSource(imageStream);

        }
```

So during the time of invoking this code line `camera.CaptureFileAsync(CameraCaptureUIMode.Photo);` the camera UI comes and while tapping on the screen the picture captures. My issue comes after this step. After capturing the image a default cropping screen appears , I don't want this intermediate step to be performed, In my application based on the frame detected i need to implement a new cropping method / region. So my question is how i can disable this intermediate cropping functionality in WinRT,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have property for that:

```
camera.PhotoSettings.AllowCropping = false;
```

[Details](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.media.capture.cameracaptureuiphotocapturesettings.allowcropping.aspx) can be found here.